# Unable to trigger render when switching between multiple objects containing content in different languages

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I read [Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) but can't solve the issue.

I'm creating a small single page app that contains images and text.
When the user clicks a button I want the language to change.

Currently I am storing the content in two files that export an object.

```
export default {
    projects: [
        {
            title: 'Project Title',
            year: 2016,
            ...
        },
        
    ]
}
```

and importing that

```
import contentEn from './assets/content.en.js'
import contentDe from './assets/content.de.js'
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { App },
    data: {
        mainContent: {
            content: contentEn
        }
    },
    methods: {
        switchToGerman(){
            this.mainContent.content = contentDe
        }
    },
    template: '<App :mainData="mainContent"/>',

})
```

When I assign another object to `mainContent.content` the rendering is not triggered.

I understand that adding and deleting properties from object don't lead to change detection but I switch out a whole object. I tried assigning it with `this.$set` with no success.

I also tried [this](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/component-not-updating-when-data-changes/3163/6) and googled a lot but can't get it work.

Or is my approach just wrong?

Thank you for helping,
best,
ccarstens

EDIT:

See below the code for the `App` component and the `ProjectElement`

```
// App.vue
<template>
  <div id="app">
      <button @click="switchGerman">Deutsch</button>
      <ProjectElement v-for="(project, key) in fullData.content.projects" :key="key" :content="project"/>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ProjectElement from './components/ProjectElement'


export default {
    name: 'App',
    props: [
        'mainData'
    ],
    data () {
        return{
            fullData: {}
        }
    },
    methods: {
        switchGerman(){

            this.$root.switchToGerman()


        }
    },
    created(){
        this.fullData = this.$props.mainData
    },
    watch: {
        mainData: {
            handler: function(newData){
                this.fullData = newData
            },
            deep: true
        }
    },
    components: {
        ProjectElement,
    }
}
</script>
```

And the ProjectElement

```
//ProjectElement.vue
<template>
    <article :class="classObject" v-observe-visibility="{
    callback: visibilityChanged,
    throttle,
    intersection: {
        threshold
    }
    }">
        <header v-html="description"></header>
        <div class="content">
            <carousel :per-page="1" :pagination-enabled="false">
                <slide v-for="(slide, index) in projectContent.media" :key="index">
                    <VisualElement :content="slide" ></VisualElement>
                </slide>
            </carousel>
        </div>
    </article>
</template>

<script>

    import {Carousel, Slide} from 'vue-carousel'
    import VisualElement from './VisualElement'
    export default {
        name: "ProjectElement",
        components: {
            Carousel,
            Slide,
            VisualElement
        },
        props: [
            'content'
        ],
        data () {
            return {
                projectContent: {},
                isVisible: false,
                throttle: 300,
                threshold: 0.8
            }
        },
        created(){
            this.projectContent = this.content
        },
        methods: {
            visibilityChanged(isVisible){
                this.isVisible = isVisible
            }
        },
        computed: {
            description(){
                return `
                    <p>${ this.projectContent.title } - ${this.projectContent.year}</p>
                    <p>${ this.projectContent.description }</p>
                `
            },
            classObject(){
                return {
                    visible: this.isVisible,
                    'project-element': true
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What happens if `content` is not nested inside `mainContent`?

Comment: Nothing much happens, nesting it was a proposed solution in the tread in the second link..

Comment: Post a more complete example, such as where/how you're calling `switchToGerman`, the `App` component, etc. The code that you've posted should work, so something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing deep copy:

```
switchToGerman () {
  const copyContent = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.mainContent))
  copyContent.content = contentDe
  this.mainContent = copyContent
}
```

Comment: I tried this but since I didn't watch the `content` property in `ProjectElement.vue` it didn't help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution (thank you @EricGuan for pointing out that the mistake must lay somewhere else)

As you can see in the original post I created a watcher for the `mainData` property and expected that this would trigger the re render.

What was missing is, that I didn't watch the `content` property on the `ProjectElement` component, thus not triggering a re render there.

I added this to `ProjectElement.vue` and now it works like a charm:

```
    watch: {
        content(newContent){
            this.projectContent = newContent
        }
    },
```

Thank you everybody for helping me! <3